# Google ga4, no real time subdomains, what to do?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I operate an SAAS, where every customer has a custom subdomain.

We used the real-time view in google analytics, to see what customers and how many of them were on-line so that we can know whether bouncing their instance would inconvenience them.

GA4 lacks this feature. You can show host information in a report, but that's always historical data.

We were thinking about moving to plausible analytics or some such, but I see they don't support this feature either.

Any suggestions about what we should move to?